# When testing actions on google, is it possible to test on a real device with a different account than created the action?

Tags: testing, actions-on-google

We have created an action with an email belonging to the developer.

Using the developer's account we have successfully tested in the simulator and on a Google Home Mini. See: "Testing on real hardware" https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/submit

Now want to test on a real device with a different account.

In the simulator I am able to share the action with my team members for others to test before deploying. See "Sharing your project" https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying

The team members are able to access and test on the simulator, but we are having trouble getting them testing on a support device.

After sharing in the the simulator, should they be able to test on any supported devices?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to test with a different account.

1. Once you share the project with team members, they can go into the console and begin testing. They will need to enable testing specifically for their account. Then, it should work on any device with the Assistant linked to that account (you may need to also enable voice match on smart speakers).
2. Alternately if these team members do not need to make changes, and it's not a smart home action, you can create an [alpha release](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments#setup) and share with their emails. They'll need to opt-in, but afterwards can access it on any device with their account.

Comment: Thanks! We got it working using option #1 -- finally! Not sure why it wasn't working, but yesterday was a headache